# How can I better check whether two char variables are in some set of values?

Tags: c++

Recently, our professor has requested that we use two `char` variables (day) to receive the input from the user.

The code below works fine as a check to ensure that either Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, Su are the only two characters which are entered together as a pair. If anything else is received as input, it'll loop and ask the user for valid input.

The input should be case-insensitive, meaning that, for example, `"mO"` and `"tu"` are acceptable. It seems like there is a lot of repetition that is happening. Is there a way to clean this up?

```
cout << "Please enter the day of the week did you made the long distance call (Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su): ";
cin >> dayOne >> dayTwo;

while ((dayOne != 'M' && dayOne != 'm' || dayTwo != 'O' && dayTwo != 'o') &&
       (dayOne != 'T' && dayOne != 't' || dayTwo != 'U' && dayTwo != 'u') &&
       (dayOne != 'W' && dayOne != 'w' || dayTwo != 'e' && dayTwo != 'E') &&
       (dayOne != 'T' && dayOne != 't' || dayOne != 'H' && dayTwo != 'h') &&
       (dayOne != 'F' && dayOne != 'f' || dayTwo != 'R' && dayTwo != 'r') &&
       (dayOne != 'S' && dayOne != 's' || dayTwo != 'A' && dayTwo != 'a') &&
       (dayOne != 'S' && dayOne != 's' || dayTwo != 'U' && dayTwo != 'u'))
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << endl << "You have entered an invalid day. Please re-enter a day in the correct format (Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su): ";
    cin >> dayOne >> dayTwo;
}
```

Comment: That's a strange requirement. Are you not allowed to make a string from the 2 chars?

Comment: You can convert to lower or upper case and compare against that, reducing the number of checks by two. You can use `switch` statements, perhaps nested. You could move to using an actual `std::string` and using `operator==`. And so on, and so forth.

Comment: @cigien Unfortunately, no we all thought it was strange ourselves and could easily using a tool from the string library to compare the input...

Comment: Are you allowed to use a matrix or vector of valid values? That would help in cycling it somehow in a generic way.

Comment: @Pipetus unfortunately we have not learned vectors yet. The current prof just seems like he was hired off the streets due to COVID and it's extremely frustrating.

Comment: sigh, another artificial and unenlightening exercise :-(

Comment: @underscore_d Yeah tell me about it. The prof doesn't even come up with the excercises. He takes them from the textbook. It's extremely frustrating for those who actually wish to learn something...is there any places which you could recommend excercises that might challenge on a bit more?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/cpp ? :)

Comment: Thanks @crsn I will give that a shot!

Comment: Define weekday string array, loop over this array using `strcmp()` over user input from STDIN stream. Just before comparison - change letter casing to upper or lower depending on your array definition.

Comment: See `std::toupper` and `std::tolower` to convert to all uppercase or all lowercase to reduce the number of comparisons.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could write a [fold-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) that compares 2 characters to a string:

```
template<typename ...Days>
bool any_of(char a, char b, Days ...days)
{
    return (... || (a == days[0] && b == days[1]));
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
while (! any_of(std::tolower(dayOne), std::tolower(dayTwo), "mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa", "su"))
    // keep asking for input
```

Here's a [demo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/q7TxKk).

This should satisfy the requirement of using 2 `char` inputs.

Comment: Not sure what a fold expression is, but I'm definitely open to doing some research. Thank you opening the doors to something new for me.

Comment: This a very elegant solution however if I gave a new programmer an assignment and they came back with a C++ fold expression, I would assume they copied the code from somewhere. Generally the point of these sorts of assignments is to get an understanding of basic control flow.

Comment: @mascoj True, but in that case, I don't think this is a good assignment. The question should be such that basic control flow *is* the best solution, if that's the concept that the student should be learning. At least, this way the student can learn something new, that is also a better way to solve the given problem :)

Comment: @mascoj I'd say you should be glad your assignments prompt students to bountiful googling. They might've copied it today, but they'll know it tomorrow.

Comment: OP looks like to use `using namespace Std;`. Without warning that, providing a function called `any_of` is not a good idea. IMO this function name is reserved for `std::any_of`, unless move your one to a separate namespace.

Answer (score 21):

You typically use `tolower` or `toupper` to convert your `char` variable to the correct case first. I like using [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/tolower) - it looks marginally better.

```
dayOne = tolower(dayOne);
dayTwo = tolower(dayTwo);

while (
    (dayOne != 'm' || dayTwo != 'o') &&
    (dayOne != 't' || dayTwo != 'u') &&
    (dayOne != 'w' || dayTwo != 'e') &&
    (dayOne != 't' || dayTwo != 'h') &&
    (dayOne != 'f' || dayTwo != 'r') &&
    (dayOne != 's' || dayTwo != 'a') &&
    (dayOne != 's' || dayTwo != 'u'))
{
    ...
}
```

You can further change it by using [`memcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) to compare both characters at once, but I am not sure it would simplify the code.

Comment: Unless you've assembled the two characters into a string, using `memcmp` will invoke undefined behavior, and if you've assembled them into a string, you'd be better off doing string comparisons.

Comment: @Mark: `memcmp` is simpler than `strcmp` - it doesn't have to check for terminating `0` bytes in both strings, it can just compare a fixed number of bytes.  (Especially good when that number is a compile-time constant).  In this case you'd use it by doing `char day[] = {dayOne, dayTwo};` (note that this isn't a C string, there's no `0` terminator).  For 2 byte compares in particular, you can expect a compiler to make this efficient by having the 2 bytes of string data in a register and doing integer comparisons.  e.g. in NASM syntax, `cmp eax, "mo" / je match`.

Comment: @PeterCordes, true, you don't need the terminating null to use memcmp.  But you still need to assemble them into a single unit -- `memcmp(&dayOne, "mo", 2)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Mark: yes, of course it is, that's why I didn't say to do that.  Another thing you could do is `int bytes = dayOne | (dayTwo << 8)`, then you could even `switch` on that integer value, using cases like `case 'm' | ('o'<<8):`.  (The transform from 2 chars to an int could be wrapped in a macro or function).  Likely a sequence of `memcmp` will compile similarly to that switch.  (This is endian agnostic since I'm just shifting both compare operands, and I didn't need casting to `uint32_t` because `<<` promotes the left side to `int` if it's narrower, and int is wide enough for 2 ASCII chars.)

Comment: Oh, @Harjit Singh already had this idea and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 13):

Another approach that might be worth mention is to organize your data, so that you can use std functions against it (`std::find`)

```
// Example program
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<std::string> days = {
        "mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa", "su"
    };

    bool found = false;

    while (found == false) {
        char dayOne, dayTwo;
        std::cout << "Please enter the first letter of the day" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> dayOne;
        std::cout << "Please enter the second letter of the day" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> dayTwo;

        std::string fullDay;
        fullDay += std::tolower(dayOne);
        fullDay += std::tolower(dayTwo);

        found = std::find(days.begin(), days.end(), fullDay) != days.end();
        std::cout << (found ? "correct day " : "invalid day, please try again ")
                  << fullDay
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

run it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/S1QzNdU6U)

Comment: Appreciate the response, but we have not covered vectors yet in the course unfortunately. However, I keep on seeing vectors everytime I google something CPP related so I will start looking up the use for them!

Comment: Dynamically allocated std::vector is overkill for this situation since you already know the size in advance and don't add any more items to it.

Comment: @hoz true, I can provide an optimized version, but for the purpose of the example (showing `std containers`), should be enough

Comment: I wonder why you didn't use `std::any_of` instead!!!

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
switch (256 * tolower(dayOne) + tolower(dayTwo))
{
    case 256 * 'm' + 'o':
        // Monday
    case 256 * 't' + 'u':
        // Tuesday
}
```

and so on?

Comment: For anyone wondering how this works, what it does is convert each two-`char` string into a single `int`, using the underlying ASCII representations; the first character is shifted left 8 spaces and the second left unshifted.  This effectively converts the strings into `int`s, allowing them to be used in a `switch` statement.

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 256? This should not be a hard-coded literal. For readability and self-documenting code, you should define it as a symbolic constant. (Also...assuming ASCII is non-portable and should probably be avoided, especially for someone learning to program.)

Comment: @CodyGray - this doesn't appear to assume ASCII though, it should still work with EBCDIC. It does assume 8-bit char (so maybe shifting left by `CHAR_BIT` would be better, though watch out for systems where `char` is signed), though whether that's really of relevance to someone learning programming today rather than in the 1980s is another matter.

Comment: @JustinTime-ReinstateMonica or you could say it is just `dayOne << 8 | dayTwo` :]

Comment: @antispinwards: you actually *don't* want to shift by 32 on systems with 32-bit char (so `sizeof(int) = 1`).  Shifting by `8` is guaranteed to not overflow an `int`, or at least not an `unsigned int`, if your inputs are 7-bit chars that zero-extend to `int`.  So probably we should be doing `(unsigned char)tolower(dayOne) | ((unsigned)(unsigned char)tolower(dayTwo)<<8)` to make sure that 8-bit chars zero-extend to `unsigned int`, without any signed overflow when left-shifting into a possibly 16-bit int.  (The code is endian agnostic, but I shifted dayTwo because I like little-endian.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - yeah, that's the kind of thing that led me to start using Rust. I'd rather fight the borrow checker than the insane integer rules in C/C++.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if you're using/allowed regexes, but I'd solve it like this:

```
bool isDayOfTheWeek(char a, char b)
{
    std::string day({a, b});
    std::regex pattern("Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su", std::regex_constants::icase);
    return std::regex_search(day, pattern);
}
```

Then simply:

```
cout << "Please enter the day of the week did you made the long distance call (Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su): ";
cin >> dayOne >> dayTwo;

while (!isDayOfTheWeek(dayOne, dayTwo))
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << endl << "You have entered an invalid day. Please re-enter a day in the correct format (Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su): ";
    cin >> dayOne >> dayTwo;
}
```

Comment: Put away that bazooka; this is only a fly!

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, but that fly isn't going to be bothering anyone any more! :D

Comment: @PaulEvans I actually like it, as I find it very readable. I am not sure the professor wanted this though! :)

Comment: All this feedback has been filled with lots of good info that will require me to reserach on my own. Super appreciative of all the feedback for a new programmer like myself! A lot of it is new to me which I like so I can look up on my own time.

Answer (score 2):

I would first convert inputs to lowercase, which cuts on the amount of possible combinations. Then I would solve it with a single if-statement per day:

```
// returns 0-6 for valid days, -1 for invalid ones
int dayOfWeek(char a, char b) {
    a = tolower(a); // requires #include <cctype>
    b = tolower(b);
    if (a == 'm' && b == 'o') return 0;
    // 5 more here
    if (a == 's' && b == 'u') return 6;
    return -1;      // date was invalid
}
```

And then I would use it as [@PaulEvans suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62439374/15472):

```
cout << "Please enter the day of the week did you made the long distance call (Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su): ";
cin >> dayOne >> dayTwo;

int day = -1;

while ((day = dayOfWeek(dayOne, dayTwo)) == -1)
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << endl << "You have entered an invalid day. Please re-enter a day in the correct format (Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su): ";
    cin >> dayOne >> dayTwo;
}

// day is 0 for monday, ... 6 for sunday
```